# How to subtract a given range based on it's own value on spreadsheet

Tags: excel-formula

[Sample sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W5ZhpzgcZPWB9n2j0qn8PPganSyuBJkKT3Cxle7fTvQ/edit#gid=0)

I want to subtract a given range based on it's own value. Say, for example, numbers 96-99 have a 5% to decrease by 1 to 2, 90-95 have a 10% chance to decrease from 2 to 4, 85-89 have a 15% chance to decrease by 4 to 6, and so on. I was using a randbetween formula to choose a number in a range, but it would be better from me if the higher the number the lower the chance of it not changing at all.

Comment: so what happens to 95?  your range for decreasing skipped over 95. will it also skip over 85,75,65, etc?

Comment: I made a mistake in typing the explanation. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because RAND() and RANDBETWEEN() are volatile functions, you will need a minimum of 1 helper cell.  This solution will step you through the thought process.  in the end you will have a formula based on the nested steps.

This solution is based on the assumption your number that you are working with is an integer.

## STEP 1 - BUILD YOUR REFERENCE TABLE

Build a reference table indexed by your break points as follows.  I did it in descending order to match the way you presented the ranges in the question.  Nothing wrong with indexing in ascending order wither but the formulas would need to be edited.

[image: table]

## Step 2 - Determine your start number

This is where I made the assumption that your number is an integer.  I used RANDBETWEEN() which is a volatile function.  This means it will recalculate everytime something on the worksheet changes.  Also if this number needs to be referred to multiple times in a formula, you need to refer to its cell and not nest the RANDBETWEEN() as you would probably wind up dealing with different rand between numbers and your formula results would not be consistent.

In E2 I used the following.

```
=RANDBETWEEN(0,99)
```

This is the number we will check against.

## Step 3 - Find the probability for change and associate range

if your information was indexed in ascending order you would have a few options for formula here such as VLOOKUP.  Since the table being used is in descending order I used the following in F2 and copied right to G2 and H2:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$21,IFERROR(MATCH($E2+1,$A$2:$A$21,-1)+1,1),COLUMN(A1))
```

## Step 4 - Generate a random %  chance

In I2 use the following volatile function.  If only referred to once in a formula, it is safe to nest.

```
=RAND()
```

## Step 5 - Check to see if something happens

In J2 I used the following formula to compared the randam percentage against the probability range of doing sometime with the number from step 2.

```
=IF(I2<=F2,"subtract","do nothing")
```

## Step 6 - Determine random amount to subtract

At this stage we determine the random amount regardless of if it is needed or not.  while its an unnecessary calculation when broken out, since it calculates regardless, it would be necessary as part of an IF function where it would only calculate if required.  In K2 I used the following:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(G2,H2)
```

## Step 7 - Determine the final number

In L2 check if you need to subtract and if so subtract the appropriate amount:

```
=E2-IF(J2="subtract",K2,0)
```

Now that is the process.  It can be reduced to a single ugly formula by substituting formulas from on cell into the formula that calls for that cell.  In this case it might look something like this:

```
=E3-IF(IF(RAND()<=INDEX($B$2:$D$21,IFERROR(MATCH($E3+1,$A$2:$A$21,-1)+1,1),COLUMN(A2)),"subtract","do nothing")="subtract",RANDBETWEEN(INDEX($B$2:$D$21,IFERROR(MATCH($E3+1,$A$2:$A$21,-1)+1,1),COLUMN(B2)),INDEX($B$2:$D$21,IFERROR(MATCH($E3+1,$A$2:$A$21,-1)+1,1),COLUMN(C2))),0)
```

Now that is really ugly and hard to check if its working or not.  That is why if you dont need to cram it all into one cell it can be better to break things out into parts.

you can also tweak that big ugly formula a bit to look like the following so it only a slightly less big ugly formula:

```
=E3-IF(RAND()<=INDEX($B$2:$D$21,IFERROR(MATCH($E3+1,$A$2:$A$21,-1)+1,1),1),RANDBETWEEN(INDEX($B$2:$D$21,IFERROR(MATCH($E3+1,$A$2:$A$21,-1)+1,1),2),INDEX($B$2:$D$21,IFERROR(MATCH($E3+1,$A$2:$A$21,-1)+1,1),3)),0)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is way out of my league. I need to apply that to around 40 columns where the number are not in order. i didn't realize the order would matter.

Comment: The numbers you are applying it to do not need to be in order.  Your reference table for probability and what you do will be set up once and referred by each of your formulas.  The number you would need to apply this to would take the place of E3  and change the $E3 to E3 when you copy it from column to column so the letter can update.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually just going to bring the columns into this one by one so I won't need to change anything. I was getting weird results with numbers that were in random order but it must have been an input error on my part because it works fine now. I have run into another problem. I need to have numbers that will never change. Ill show an example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wVhgKIITFHxbe0lalm00SsLioEzdUqYf_JsI71AnVPE/edit#gid=0. I need the ones with 1,2, and 3 in column G to apply the formula to E and stay the same if they are 4 or 5.

Comment: I think I've got it working correctly. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wVhgKIITFHxbe0lalm00SsLioEzdUqYf_JsI71AnVPE/edit?usp=sharing  Thanks again.